# gitlab, register gitlab-runner interactive with tag

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I register gitlab-runner about the command line [interactively](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/blob/master/docs/commands/README.md#interactive-registration).

Some projects has a .gitlab-ci.yml to specify gitlab-runner to build the projects. For example a project to build a custom image.

`build_iso:
  script: make
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - out/custom-image.iso
    expire_in: 1 day
  only:
    - master
  tags:
    - custom-image`

I need an option to tag my runner at registration with `custom-image`, to build this project on the same runner every time.

I can't found in the documentation an option to tag a runner. It's generally possible to tag a runner during registration?

When it's possible, how can I add a tag during the interactively registration?

Regards, Volker

Answer (score 1):

Once the container is up, use the flag

> --tag-list

with the docker exec command :

```
docker exec -it ID gitlab-runner register -n \
--name myrunner \
--url  mygitlab.com\
--registration-token {{TOKEN}} \
--tag-list tag1,tag2 \
--run-untagged true \
--executor shell
```